# Save a UIImage and reused it on UIImageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, save

I currently have the ability to take a photo or load from the camera and place an image in the UIImageView in my app be i want the ability to have a button that will save the image so when i reload the app the image is still in the UIImageView.

My though was a button to save the image once you have loaded it and in the

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
```

have the code to load the image that was saved but i don't know how to approach this.

Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert images to `NSData` using either `UIImagePNGRepresentation` or `UIImageJPGRepresentation`, then save the data to file calling one of `NSData`'s `writeToFile...` methods.

Then when you restart your application, you can get the image by calling `[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]]`

-- EDIT --

**Save image**

```
UIImage *image = ...;
NSString *cachedFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *cachedImagePath = [cachedFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:cachedImagePath atomically:YES];
```

**Load image**

```
NSString *cachedFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *cachedImagePath = [cachedFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cachedImagePath]];
```

I used `NSCachesDirectory` since I'm assuming you don't want to have this image backed up (either through iCloud or iTunes). If you do then you'd want to use `NSDocumentDirectory` instead.