# save all app data Xcode

Tags: ios, firebase

I'm starting now with swift and wanted to know how do I save the data from my app. I have text and photos in my app. how can I save this using the firebase or saving directly to the user's iphone?

I want the user to terminate an action and the app to save automatically.

an example the user added an image in the imageview using the photos library closed and left the app. when he reopened everything he did this as he had left.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save UIImageView image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228241/save-uiimageview-image)

Comment: Did you go through the Firebase [Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start) It covers [Reading  and Writing Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write), queries and more! It's a good read and will really help you get started. One part of your question is vague; what does *terminate an action and app save automatically* mean? Please take a moment and review [How To Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)